Can I increase basement ceiling height by lifting ground floor joists?
I have a house where the basement is 6' tall and the ground floor above is 12' tall.  The ground floor is also 1' below grade, so I step down to the main living space when entering the home.
I want to increase the basement height by raising the entire ground floor. Current construction is fairly traditional, with the floor joists sitting on a still plate directly on the foundation wall. I'm thinking about a solution where I put some form of engineered beam directly on the foundation flush with the wall and the joists sit on top.
No matter what I search however, I can't find any reference to such a solution online.
Can anyone help me understand a couple of things?
1 - does the design I have described have a name?
2 - does anyone have any input on this approach?

Not sure what you are planning. You can certainly lift the whole house and build up the foundation. Are you talking about building a replacement floor higher up inside the current walls?

A few pictures of ducks will be much cheaper.  You are looking at lifting of the whole house which is specialize work and slow.  It might be cheaper to drop/dig out the basement floor, if it can be done without disturbing the foundation footings.

why wood? why not use concrete to make the foundation taller?

It would seem that digging out the basement floor would be an easier approach and less stressful to the rest of the house.

For search terms, lifting a house and/or moving a house should help.  What you use to increase the foundation height is not as important

Do you mean lift just the floor and not the whole house?  If your wall studs sit directly on the sill, you might be able to pull it off without redoing the walls but it would still be a colossal pain.  Also don't forget you'd have to adjust all the doorways, radiators, fixtures, plumbing, light switches, etc.  Sometimes more is less.

Ground Floor is the UK term for the ground-level floor - called the first floor in the US. I think the OP wants to lift the floor by about 2 feet, so that the basement is 8 foot high, and the ground floor is 10 foot high. The problem with doing this is that there are rules on how high sockets and light switches should be from the floor. You'll need to move these which is a lot of work, and if the cables run from the floor, it will need a complete re-wire

If your house is platform framed, then you can't just raise the floor by raising the joists.  That would raise the wall and the rest of the house above it, since the wall sits on the floor.

If your house if balloon framed, then may be able to do what you want.  But it won't be easy or straightforward.

You basically have three options that I can think of off the top of my head and fall inline with what others have described.  Whatever option you chose, get a building permit from your local building department.  They will most likely tell you to engage the services of a structural engineer and/or an architect.
Option 1 - Lower the basement floor
Depending on your ground conditions, you may be able to underpin your foundation walls, break out your basement floor, dig down and put in a new foundation floor.
Some problems with this method might be that you home is already on top of bedrock.  Digging out rock would be a royal pain in the arse.  Another problem may be ground water level.  You tend not to want to have your basement below ground water level.  This leads right out to the next potential problem.  You may not have enough clearance with the dug out basement to continue to have a gravity fee to your sewer system.
One of the nice benefits of this approach is that you can selectively lower the floor in the rooms you want.  If there is some storage room you barely use, no need to lower the floor there perhaps.
Option 2 - Jack the house and raise the foundation
I personally believe this is your better option usually.  Contact house movers and see what they would quote you just to jack the house off the foundation.  They will punch holes in your foundation and slide beam through under load bearing walls.  They will also "shim" add blocking where you might have a step in floor elevation.  They will then jack or raise the beam up off the ground which will separate the house from the foundation.  They will then build cribbing under the beams before lowering the beams on to the cribbing for support while you work on the foundation.
While the foundation is clear, use this time to build up your perimeter foundation walls.  If you do not have concrete or masonry foundations walls, you may want to consider replacing your entire foundation wall at this time.  Otherwise, either use concrete blocks / masonry or form and pour a concrete filler along the top of the wall.  Check with a structural engineer / your local building department to see if you will need any reinforcing steel or anchors to tie the top of your wall to the old one, and if so you may want to pre position some anchors for your new sill plate.  Once all is said and done on your foundation walls, and you have all the waterproofing and building envelop details complete, raise the support beams, remove the cribbing, and lower the house back down.  Slide out the beams and then rebuild the area where the beams were.
As part of this process, you will need to disconnect any ducts, pipes, wires, etc that are connected to the basement and move through the floor before raising the house.  When the house is back on the new foundation you will need to go around and reattach everything.
This approach will raise the basement ceiling under the whole house unless you figure out a way to sever a portion of the house.
Option 3 - Building a new floor
This option is a little complicated as all your walls are probably sitting on the joist supporting your current floor.  You would need to support your wall, then trim off the bottom of it.  You would then need to remove the joist and flooring underneath.  you would then need to build up your foundation wall, add blocking, or  build pedestals under each new joist.  Finally you would have to slide a joist and flooring system under the walls so there is contact with your new flooring system and the wall you cut the bottoms off of.
Not an impossible approach, but would take plenty of planning.  Somethings to watch out for would be changes in direction of your floor support system.  You will still need to adjust plumbling, duct work, supply lines, etc.  Depending on how much you raise the floor, you might also want/need to move all your wall sockets.  You may also find all your light switches need to be changed as well as they are not where you expect them to be when fumbling in the dark.

If the basement floor is dug out, something will likely need to be done to hold the ground back below the foundation such as pouring concrete.  The foundation can become unstable is the earth below it is free to collapse inward.

There are companies that specialize in lifting and/or moving houses, and I would definitely hire one of those; among other things, they carry insurance against something going wrong. It is unclear whether you would have to empty the house first; you certainly couldn't occupy it while this work is going on.
A ballpark estimate I heard a decade ago was $30,000 just for the lift, plus of course the cost of building up the foundation to the new height. Depends on the structure, and presumably more now.
Note that this presumes that the structure of the house is strong enough to permit this. One of my neighbors wanted to get someone to help move the house back onto its foundation, but discovered that the main roof beam was cracked. Nobody wanted the liability of trying to move the house without fixing that beam, and nobody wanted the liability of trying to fix that beam while the house was partly off its foundation. In the end, they demolished and rebuilt.
On the other hand, another house a few blocks away went through exactly the process you are describing: lift, raise foundation, put the house back down. I have no idea what the cost was.
Note that another solution may be to dig the basement floor deeper, depending on what the house is resting on. I knew somebody who was doing that, doing most of the earth moving work himself over multiple years. I have no idea how, or if, he was able to get insurance which would permit that.
Afterthought; There is one other approach, if all you need to gain is a couple inches. A friend of mine was in that position and consulting an engineer, who told him that, in his case, he could sister the floor joists above with steel 4" C-beams to provide strength, then cut the joists back level with the beams. The living room floor would be springier than it had been, but would be structurally strong enough. The insurance company was actually okay with him doing this as a DIY project, as long as he did it to the engineers spec; I spent some time assisting with that project. Again, hiring an engineer for a consultation was the best starting point.

This is correct. I've seen it done several times, too. All electrical and plumbing need to be detached, then it's jack time. They'll raise the house and support it with dunnage while masons modify or rebuild the foundation, then set it back down. If the company know their stuff you won't even see much in the way of wall cracks.

As to the alternate plan, you'd have to undermine the footings in stages and flow concrete under them to extend downward. It's probably more hassle and expense than lifting the house. Of course, it saves having a taller house.

And this is why cost is off-topic.  I have a more recent estimate at $20,000.  Note that size of the house matters.  My estimate was based entirely on pictures that I took and measurements that I gave them.  A professional can give you a rough estimate on that basis to determine if you want an in-person estimate (where they come out and take their own measurements and observations).

Absolutely. I was giving the quote only to give people an order of magnitude guesstimate, so they had some idea of what they were getting into. I would expect that costs in my area, where million dollar houses are becoming the norm, to be higher than elsewhere. Good suggestion to try photos and measurements first.

My neighbours dropped a moved house on their lot.  They had the basement/foundation dug out under after dropping the house. Took a month or two or three.   Quite interesting and the house is still standing after ~30 plus years.

Raising houses around here is pretty common.  This is done to get the first floor above the flood elevation, and may entail raising the whole house 3-4 feet.

I am technically in the flood plain, so I've considered it. And more headroom in the basement would be a good thing

On the other end of the cost spectrum, one of my neighbors a few years back replaced their entire foundation. Their house was lifted like 2 feet off, and the entire foundation was demolished and replaced beneath it and the house put back down where it was. They said it cost them $120,000. Which seems like a lot, but considering just how much work was involved with that, it actually seemed like a pretty good bargain.

You have the right idea. I've done a few. Jack it up carefully. Little here a little there. Use proper beams in the process. 1-2 courses of block. Key being slowly, methodically. Plenty of jacks. And again properly supported.

You need to consult with architect. Your modification can result with building collapse or can be done at easy or need some preparations/additional supports, etc... - need architect to look at it.

I would start with a structural engineer rather than an architect.
